# Bitdefender blocks pyinstaller when I install it

Tags: python

So if I type `pip install pyinstaller` it will instantly get a disinfection from bitdefender, so I can't download pyinstaller. And the most weird thing is. Yesterday I can install it, but suddenly bitdefender remove a single file then I have to reinstall it. Until I get this error

btw this is the output

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.2-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\users\\windows\\appdata\\local\\pip\\cache\\wheels\\65\\6f\\54\\0f682e8590de992d07a17ce07282267734cb150e537dfc4390\\pyinstaller-4.2-py3-none-any.whl'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add it to the exclusion list. Below is the URL to do that.

https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/13427/

Please try and let me know if you need help. Thanks!